# JQuery function-writing 101: how can I re-use this function rather than re-creating it?

Tags: jquery, slider, lightbox

This is for the same page as my last question (now solved), but the hosting has gone down so I can't show a live example.
I am using Fearless Flyer's contentslider, because it has the simplest mark-up & code that I found. See it here:
http://demo.fearlessflyer.com/html/demo/content-slider/

However, quite obviously it's made for one slider per page, not multiple sliders. If I try to implement it unchanged with two sliders, the 2nd slider doesn't work, because the value of the negative margins for sliding are multiplied on top of the calculations that already happened for the first slider- so the margin goes zooming off -4000px to the right, where there are no photos to display.

I've gotten it to work with two sliders, using the following mark-up:

I have two sliders, once called "lightbox_gallery" and one called "lightbox_5gruende".

```
<div id="lightbox_gallery" class="lightbox_window">
    <div id="mother_gallery">
        <ul>
            <li><img id="test" src="gallery_02.jpg" /><a class="next" href="#">next</a></li>
            <li><img src="gallery_01.jpg" /><a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a></li>
            <li><img src="gallery_02.jpg" /><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a><a class="startover"             href="#">startover</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!--end lightbox div -->

<div id="lightbox_5gruende" class="lightbox_window">
    <div id="mother_5gruende">
        <ul>
            <li><img id="test" src="gallery_03.jpg" /><a class="next" href="#">next</a></li>
            <li><img src="gallery_03.jpg" /><a class="next" href="#">next</a><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a></li>
            <li><img src="gallery_02.jpg" /><a class="previous" href="#">prev</a><a class="startover" href="#">startover</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!--end lightbox div -->
```

And then this incredibly hacky script:

```
$(window).load(function() {

var theImage = $('#lightbox_gallery ul li img');
var theImage2 = $('#lightbox_5gruende ul li img');
var theWidth = 790;

$('#mother_gallery').css({
    //stuff
});
    //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 
var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
$('ul').css({
    width: function(){
    return totalWidth;  
}

});
$('#mother_5gruende').css({
    //stuff
});
    //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul 
var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
$('ul').css({
    width: function(){
    return totalWidth;  
}

}); 
$(theImage).each(       
    function(intIndex){             
            $(this).nextAll('a')
            .bind("click", function(){
                if($(this).is(".next")) {

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * 790)              
                    }, 1000)                    

                } else if($(this).is(".previous")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * 790)              
                    }, 1000)    


                } else if($(this).is(".startover")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (0)              
                    }, 1000)

                }

            });//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()

// THEN REPEATING THE SAME WITH SLIGHTLY DIFFERENT NAMES BECAUSE I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO WRITE A REUSABLE FUNCTION //

$(theImage2).each(      
    function(intIndex2){                
            $(this).nextAll('a')
            .bind("click", function(){
                if($(this).is(".next")) {

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex2 + 1) * 790)             
                    }, 1000)                    

                } else if($(this).is(".previous")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex2 - 1) * 790)             
                    }, 1000)    


                } else if($(this).is(".startover")){

                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (0)              
                    }, 1000)

                }

            });//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()

});//doc ready
```

This is so ugly it hurts! It works, but I don't want to have two entirely separate slider functions doing the same things for images in separate sliders.

How can I rewrite this so that the calculations inside of $(theImage).each could be used for both sliders?

Comment: It's always the case that the second UL in the mark-up calculates the negative margins too high by a factor of 2- ie on the first UL the final margin-left is -2370px, and on the second UL the final margin-left is -4740px, so I guess something (probably intIndex?) isn't re-set to 0 before it calculates values for the 2nd UL. How could I structure it so that intIndex is re-set to 0 for each UL?

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like:

```
function animateParentUl( $element, marginValue ) {
    $element.parent('li').parent('ul')
        .animate({"margin-left": marginValue }, 1000)   
}
```

And then call it as:

```
$(theImage2).each(      
    function(intIndex2){                
            $(this).nextAll('a')
            .bind("click", function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                if($this.is(".next")) {
                    animateParentUl( $this, (-(intIndex2 + 1) * 790) );
                } else if($this.is(".previous")){
                    animateParentUl( $this, (-(intIndex2 - 1) * 790) );
                } else if($this.is(".startover")){
                    animateParentUl( $this, 0 );
                }

            });//close .bind()                                   
});//close .each()
```

Comment: Thank you, separating out the function works, but it does the same thing as before- the in the 2nd instance of the gallery, the value of the negative margin is much too high. Trying to work out how to re-set it to 0 for each instance of a gallery.